# Setting up a temporary mail server

Tags: email, fedora, email-server

I have to accept e-mails on a certain domain name for a short while. Is there a quick and easy way of setting up a temporary e-mail system? It doesn't even have to have an interface in particular, just dump received mail so I can read it.

If I need to set up a solution on a box, it will need to be Linux. I am using Fedora 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use "[Google Apps for My Domain](http://google.com/a)"? It's free and allows you to use Google apps (such as email, docs, calendar) with whatever domain you choose.If you don't like Google, I'm sure there are other such online services.

Comment: If you can change MX records this takes only minutes to setup for basic services.

Answer (score 1):

[Postfix](http://www.postfix.org/) is relatively simple to install and configure. Once set up, you can easily make it do whatever you want with the email.

Of course, this will require an Internet connected host on which to run, so if you don't really want to go to that trouble (including running a firewall on the host for security), you should take Traveling Tech Guy's advice and use Google Apps for Domains, which is a pretty great product.

Answer (score 0):

Who is the registrar of the domain?  The solution might just be "too easy".

For example, if your registrar is 1and1.com you can simply log into the 1and1 administrator and change the DNS to say that the mail is going to be handled by 1&1.

I've done this in the past when I was transitioning a domain and, like you, needed to just "dump" the mail somewhere for a while and be able to retrieve it.

I'm sure other registrars out there provide a similar service.  Hopefully yours does.

Hope this helps.